# Cannot select a feature using ArcGIS Pro 2

Tags: editing, arcgis-pro

I have a lab full of students who are trying to work through and activity using ArcGIS Pro 2.0.1.  Students are building a polygon feature class from the same LiDAR point cloud.  I cannot see any difference in the resulting features.

When some students try to modify features using the modify features tools to split polygons and edit vertices.  Some of them are unable to select the features to modify.

What could be some other possible troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Is the layer set to selectable? (I know it's obvious, but perhaps *too* obvious) What about the spatial reference, is it compatible? Is the geometry bad, could it use a repair geometry? What about the spatial index? You could try rebuilding the spatial index.

Comment: I will check when I am back in the lab tomorrow and update this thread.  Thanks for the suggestions.